# How to get data correctly after data caching?

Tags: asp.net

If I cached a dataset object, after this table data will change, so I will get cached data that is not updated one. In this situation what to do, how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can [clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.data.dataset.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) dataset to keep orginal value, then set it to cache.

```
        HttpContext.Cache.Insert("datasetOrg", dataset.Clone());
        HttpContext.Cache.Insert("dataset", dataset);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqlcachedependency` class to achice this. When a change occurs in the table or in a specific row, the item that has a dependency is invalidated and removed from the cache. You can set a dependency on a table in Microsoft SQL Server 7.0, SQL Server 2000, and SQL Server 2005. If you are using SQL Server 2005 you can also set a dependency on a specific record.
It will work in .Net 2.0 + .[msdn article for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx)